# Resize DIV (Slider) to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have a slider that is finished, but I have 1 issue.
I need to re-size the container to the windows size.

As you can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jerman/D2wJV/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(".toggle_window").click(function(){
       $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

the slider disappear and I dont have any change to press the button so collapse the container again.
The problem I think is here #left and the high of this (height: 880px;), but I need to expand this guy at 95% of the webpage.

Which will be the best way to re-size the container?

I will appreciate your help.

Thnx in advance!

Cheers.

Comment: You cannot post a fiddle unless you post code to back the fiddle. We cannot rely on the fiddle link for future reference.

Comment: try height: 500px; on #left

Comment: Get it 13ruce1337.
Thnx!

Comment: @ Ezhil,
Well this is actually what I change all the time.
The problem is that; if your window browser is not at full screen you will not see the toggle button to toggle the content as you can see in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element `#left` height is set wrongly in your fiddle. Try setting the element height on document ready as

```
 $("#left").height($( window ).height() - $("footer").position().left + 10);
```

If you want exactly 95% try like this,

```
$("#left").height($(window).height() /100 * 95 - $("footer").position().left);
```

Comment: Hi krishna. Thnx to reply. Let me give a try and i will back.
Cheers and thank you!

DAMN! Looks good in my fiddle...
Let me try compiled this inside the page...

Comment: Hi again krishna. Something is wrong.
Inside fiddle works like a charm, but ones I try to implement this code into my page doesnt work your code.

I cant understand. Same code and doesnt work on the page?! Estrange...

Comment: check ur css. U might set height for #left

Comment: No changes.
It is may be possible to set the hight end position dynamically?

For example: I have a DIV called "Menu" (Its on the top) may be setting the highest position of the slider toggle to the end position of the Menu DIV?

It this possible?

Comment: @combo - I guess ur problem is u are not subtracting the menu height to the window height. Try setting like this `$("#left").height($(window).height() /100 * 95 - $("#menuDiv").height() - $("footer").position().left);`